# What can cause 'TypeError: undefined is not an object...`

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, undefined, marionette

From my bugtracker I am seeing this error when deployed:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.getRegion("similarRegion").show')
```

I am trying to reproduce and resolve this but having some trouble diagnosing it. Here is the code where the error is caused:

```
similarProductView() {
    var view = new SimilarProductView({ 
        collection: this.model.get('relatedProducts'),
        initialLoading: true
    });

    this.model.getRelatedProducts().always(() => {
        this.getRegion('similarRegion').show(view);
    });
},
```

My main question is what can raise this error? What I have tried, that results in different errors, are making the region a different name (causing the region to not exist), and trying to show a variable that doesn't exist.

Any ideas on what situation would raise this error? Or any suggestions on things to try to reproduce it?

Comment: It means that the left-hand side of a `.` expression is `undefined`.

Comment: so in this case it would be `this.getRegion('similarRegion')` or simply `this`?

Comment: Have you looked at `this` and `this.getRegion('similarRegion')` in a debugger or even with `console.log`?

Comment: Right, either `this` (not really possible, I don't think) or `this.getRegion('similarRegion')`

Comment: I am not sure if this is the only case but since inside always callback 'this' will refer to the deferred object on which promise is returned. You can not find getRegion method in the deferred object. I guess you will have to pass 'this' in to the arrow function.